# finding intersections between binary image and circle

Tags: matlab, image-processing, geometry, intersection

I want to draw 3 concentric circles on an ear binary image and then find coordinates of points of intersection for each circle with the image. I wrote this code but I'm not sure this works properly(I mean counting some pixels more than once?). also it doesn't look very elegant. can you suggest another method?

```
e=imread('3.jpg');
Size=size(e);
Nr = 3;
Xc = round(Size(1) / 2);
Yc = round(Size(2) / 2);
R1 = round(Xc / 5) * 2;
R2 = round(Xc / 5) * 3;
R3 = round(Xc / 5) * 4;
k = 1;
Point = zeros(100, 2);
for i=1:Size(1)
    for j=1:Size(2)
        if((((i - Xc) ^ 2) + ((j - Yc) ^ 2) == R1 ^ 2) ||...
                (((i - Xc) ^ 2) + ((j - Yc) ^ 2) == R2 ^ 2) ||...
                (((i - Xc) ^ 2) + ((j - Yc) ^ 2) == R3 ^ 2))
            if(l(i, j) == 0)
                Point(k, 1) = i;
                Point(k, 2) = j;
                k = k + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You can find the points of intersection for any two circles analytically. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).

Comment: The circles are concentric, so , there is no intersections between them. It's the intersections between edges of image and circles that is desired.